# Async.queue crashes after processing 3 initial elements of the queue with concurrency = 3

Tags: node.js, async.js

Async.queue() intially runs as expected but crashes after processing the first N elements (N = 3).

When adding callback() after running getAddress(), concurrency is totally ignored. Subsequently getAddress() runs for all tasks passed to the queue via the stream.

The problem arose when attempting to build upon [this](https://medium.com/journocoders/nightmarishly-good-scraping-with-nightmare-js-and-async-await-b7b20a38438f) tutorial.

Trying to determine the root cause and a solution. Seems possible that this is related to promise chaining?

Have attempted to refactor async.queue() following the async docs, but appears that the syntax is out of date and can't find a working example with chained promises.

```
const { csvFormat } = require('d3-dsv');
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const { readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require('fs');
const numbers = readFileSync('./tesco-title-numbers.csv', 
  {encoding: 'utf8'}).trim().split('\n');
const START = 'https://eservices.landregistry.gov.uk/wps/portal/Property_Search';

var async = require("async")
console.log(numbers)

// create a read stream 
var ArrayStream = require('arraystream')
var stream = ArrayStream.create(numbers)

// set concurrency
N = 3
var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
    let data =  getAddress(task)
    // , function(){
    // callback();
    }, 
// },
 N); 


q.drain = function() {
    stream.resume()
    console.log('all items have been processed');
    resolve()
}
// or await the end
// await q.drain()
q.saturated = function() {
  stream.pause();
}

// assign an error callback
q.error = function(err, task) {
    console.error('task experienced an error');
}

stream.on("data", function(data) {
    // console.log(data);
    q.push(data)
})


var getAddress = async id => {console.log(`Now checking ${id}`);
  const nightmare = new Nightmare({ show: true });
// Go to initial start page, navigate to Detail search
      try {
        await nightmare
          .goto(START)
          .wait('.bodylinkcopy:first-child')
          .click('.bodylinkcopy:first-child');
      } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
      }

  // Type the title number into the appropriate box; click submit
    try {
      let SOMEGLOBALVAR;
      await nightmare
        // does some work
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
      return undefined;
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determined the cause of the problem. The callback along with getAddressed needs to be returned.

```
let dataArray = []
N = 4
var q = async.queue(async function (task, callback) {

    return getAddress(task).then((response)=>{
        console.log(response); 
        dataArray.push(response);
        callback()})
} , 
 N);
```